# Data Mining Applications Using Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Would you run sensitive data mining applications (with proprietary code/data) on Amazon EC2? 
Is it 100% safe, or could somebody try to steal your IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your algorithms and code on a third-party system that you do not own or control. For some organizations that's a major security risk. For others that's an acceptable risk, especially with the security controls and certifications attained for the Amazon EC2 datacenter and service.

In short, it's totally up to your risk appetite and any legislation that may apply to your industry on data usage. You can read some more on cloud security issues here: http://blog.labslice.com/2010/09/is-cloud-insecure_2947.html

Answer (score 0):

Amazon do also provide a [virtual private cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) option. You have much greater control over security in this setup. That said, it still has a beta tag, if it is critical, I'd wait for that tag to go.